# php artisan serve equivalent for production

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, daemon, laravel-artisan

So what exactly is php artisan serve doing? I currently have a site up and running on apache and I am trying to get a websocket framework up for real time chat. The websocket is a php daemon that runs in the background and listens for events, see the package [here](https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket).

So I am using the command

```
php artisan serve brainsocket:start --port=8080
```

to start the server and everything works great, however this only works while I have the terminal open and I have read in 3-4 SO posts that artisan serve is NOT to be used in production. So how can I run the laravel package start function on port 8080 without php artisan serve, and so that it will be persistent after I close the terminal?

Comment: `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` might get you started.

Comment: And prefix the command with `nohup` so it stops running after you disconnect. You should also look at a service monitor such as upstart or supervisord to restart it if it crashes. Also, don't forget to add something to your deployment script to restart these services when code changes.

Comment: What's stopping you from using apache on port 8080?

Comment: @Brett, quite a lot.  WebSockets is not a web server.  Completely different paradigm.

Comment: Yeap, **supervisord** is my suggestion too. Give it a quick look. It's easy to install and use  and will also take care of restarting the service(websocket) if anything happens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised this hasn't been answered yet.

In production you want to run a real web server like Apache or Nginx.

With Nginx you would use `php-fpm` as your runtime and you would proxy requests to it.

Here's an example from Nginx's website.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/